# hide ajax loading symbol when poll working

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I want to hide loading symbol while poll content is working. Here is my code

```
<h:form id="indexForm" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 

        <p:growl autoUpdate="true"/>

        <p:ajaxStatus style="width:60px;height:60px;position:fixed;right:5px;top:5px"  >  

            <f:facet name="start" >  
                <p:graphicImage value="resources/resimler/loading.gif" />  
            </f:facet>  

            <f:facet name="complete">  
                <h:outputText value="" />  
            </f:facet>  

        </p:ajaxStatus>

       <p:poll id="poll" ignoreAutoUpdate="true" interval="5" process="@this,sevk" update="islemler,sevk" partialSubmit="true" rendered="true" />
 </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set global attribute of poll to false (see http://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/poll?id=poll).

Comment: Agreed. Please add a link to the documentation to your answer: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/poll?id=poll

Comment: Link to documentation added.